# How can I change an array with multiple fields in a row into an array with just one?

Tags: javascript

I have this data in a javascript variable:

```
var a = {
  "answers":[
     {"correct":null, "response":true, "text":"x" },
     {"correct":null, "response":true, "text":"y" }
  ]
}
```

I would like to send this to the server but exclude the `correct` and `text` fields.  How can I remove these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = a.answers.map(function(obj){return {response:obj.response}})
```

Here `result` will be an array of objects having just `response` field.

Comment: Thanks. I did try map but now I realize I probably did not do it correctly. I will try your suggestion.